# EV 証明書を設定し ClickOnce で作成したアプリがインストール時に「不明な公開元」として表示されてしまう

Tags: windows, visual-studio, .net

Visual Studio 2019 を使用しています。
某発行機関にEVコード証明書を発行してもらい、開発マシンにドライバーとトークンを設定。スタートアッププロジェクトのプロパティの「署名」で証明書を設定し、ClickOnce で発行したところ、クライアントマシンでSmartScreen を回避できるようになったのですが、インストール時に「セキュリティの警告」で「公開元を確認できません」と表示されます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ClickOnce の設定では「公開オプション」の「発行者名」にEV証明書の「トークン名」を設定し、マニフェストの「信頼情報にアプリケーション マニフェストを使用する」のチェックをオンにしています。

「公開元」を設定するには、他に設定が必要でしょうか？
なおアプリケーションはデスクトップアプリ(WPF)で、ターゲットフレームワークは.NET Framework 4.8です。

Comment: 既読だったり状況が違うかもしれませんがこんな記事があります。[Clickonce app is signed but publisher is still unknown when downloading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62430653/9014308) 他に関連度は不明ですがこんな記事とか。[How to Authenticode sign ClickOnce deployment with an EV SHA2 cert and avoid "Unknown Publisher"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39538466/9014308), [ClickOnceアプリケーションをBabelで難読化してからEVコードサイニング証明書で再署名する手順](https://www.proglog.work/clickonce%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%82%92babel%E3%81%A7%E9%9B%A3%E8%AA%AD%E5%8C%96%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89ev%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89/)

Comment: 紹介ありがとうございます。教えて頂いたページは既読済みです。この辺りの情報ってかなり少ないですね（汗

Answer (score 0):

ひらぽんさん、こんにちは。
同じ状況が2020年11月以降発生しています。
2020年11月（時期は少し前後する）までのVSでは問題なかったです。
現在もまだ解決に至っていません。
情報が少なくて難しいです。

Comment: 当サイトは **スレッド式の掲示板ではない** ので、回答はあくまで「質問に対する解決策としての回答」を投稿するために使ってください。 / [回答になっていない投稿は削除される可能性があります。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: 貴重な情報ありがとうございます。こちらでも引き続き調べてみたいと思います